# Why does not Visual Studio apply my changes on an HTML file?

Tags: html, visual-studio, save

I am working on a very simple ASP.NET project.

I have an HTML, a JS and a CSS file. I added some inputs and buttons to the HTML and saved it. When I am opening it in chrome my changes are not applied.

When I trying the same in page inspector it seems to work. When I check the sources in chrome it comes up with an older HTML saving without my buttons and inputs.

It seems to not saving my changes for some reason, and my JS has no acces to my HTML form as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify these steps:

1. Did you save the file/s?
2. Did you refresh the cache with Control+F5
   in browser?

If nothing of this works:

3. Did you try rebuild and re-debug/re-run ?

Comment: No problem :) I glad if it works. VS often do somethings like these. Do not forget accept this answer, you'll gain points and improve your profile.

Comment: Even more, if you accept your previous 6 questions, you will gain a lot of points

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to S.O. I recommend you read the tour and faqs. Everyone will help you a lot and better if you go on the guide :)